# key in s vs key not in s speed

Tags: python, performance, set, processing-efficiency

I have this code:

```
s = set([5,6,7,8])

if key in s:
    return True

if key not in s:
    return False
```

It seems to me that it shouldn't, in theory, differ time wise, but I may be missing something under the hood.

Is there any reason to prefer one over the other in terms of processing time or readability?

Perhaps is this an example of:

> "Premature optimization is the root of all evil"?

---

### Short Answer: No, no difference. Yes, probably premature optimization.

---

OK, I ran this test:

```
import random
s = set([5,6,7,8])
for _ in range(5000000):
    s.add(random.randint(-100000,100000000))

def test_in():
    count = 0
    for _ in range(50000):
        if random.randint(-100000,100000000) in s:
            count += 1
    print(count)

def test_not_in():
    count = 0
    for _ in range(50000):
        if random.randint(-100000,100000000) not in s:
            count += 1
    print(count)
```

When I time the outputs:

```
%timeit test_in()
10 loops, best of 3: 83.4 ms per loop

%timeit test_not_in()
10 loops, best of 3: 78.7 ms per loop
```

BUT, that small difference seems to be a symptom of counting the components. There are an average of 47500 "not ins" but only 2500 "ins". If I change both tests to pass, e.g.:

```
def test_in():
    for _ in range(50000):
        if random.randint(-100000,100000000) in s:
            pass
```

The results are nearly identical

```
%timeit test_in()
10 loops, best of 3: 77.4 ms per loop

%timeit test_not_in()
10 loops, best of 3: 78.7 ms per loop
```

In this case, my intuition failed me. I had thought that saying `it is not in the set` could have had added some additional processing time. When I further consider what a hashmap does, it seems obvious that this can't be the case.

Comment: In terms of processing time, no. In terms of clarity, I believe neither: just use `if key in s: # do something`. If you really need to put it in a function, you can use `return key in s`.

Comment: Perhaps. But you should show us an actual function, since you can't have a `return` statement outside a function. BTW, function execution paths which don't terminate in an explicit `return` statement return `None`, which is false-ish, so the 2 different forms you show won't have the same effect in an actual function.

Comment: FWIW, it's more Pythonic to write stuff like that as `return key in s`.

Comment: The speed inconsistency may be found elsewhere in the code.

Though, I agree with @PM2Ring that passing the result instead of returning True/False based on it is probably better.

Your current code appears to check for the key in the set twice.

Comment: BTW, it looks like you're still using Python 2. You should seriously consider migrating to Python 3, Python 2 will reach it's official End of Life some time in 2020.

Comment: @PM2Ring I am using this to check whether all the elements in a string are in a set, so `for char in string: if char not in my_set: return False`. This is the most stripped down example I could come up with; maybe oversimplified.

Comment: @Paul What am I using that is only python2 specific?

Comment: To see if all chars of a string are in a set you should use a set method that does the looping for you at C speed, rather than a Python loop. Eg, `s=set('abcdefg'); print(s.issuperset('caged'))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running a simple performance test in an ipython session with `timeit` confirms g.d.d.c's statement.

```
def one(k, s):
    if k in s:
        return True     

def two(k, s):
    if k not in s:
        return False     

s = set(range(1, 100))

%timeit -r7 -n 10000000 one(50, s)
## 83.7 ns ± 0.874 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)

%timeit -r7 -n 10000000 two(50, s)
## 86.1 ns ± 1.11 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)
```

Optimisations such as this aren't going to gain you a lot, and as has been pointed out in the comments will in fact reduce the speed at which you'll push out bugfixes/improvements/... due to bad readability. For this type of low-level performance gains, I'd suggest looking into [Cython](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) or [Numba](https://numba.pydata.org/).

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't see a difference.  The lookup time in a set is constant.  You hash the entry, then look it up in a hashmap.  All keys are checked in the same time, and in vs not in should be comparable.